# How to append the contents of NSSet to [NSManagedObject]?

Tags: swift, core-data, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject, nsset

**My Code**

```
isFiltering = true
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
  let words = textInSearchField.components(separatedBy: " ")

  for word in words{

    if (word).count == 0{
      continue
    }

    let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[c] %@", word)
    let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName contains[c] %@", word)
    let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id contains[c] %@", word)
    let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate, idPredicate])

    clientsEntity.predicate = orPredicate
    clientResults = try! context.fetch(clientsEntity) as! [NSManagedObject]

    let sort:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"dateSorted", ascending: false)

    for (index, ob) in clientResults.enumerated(){

      let relationship = ob.value(forKey: "assessed_by") as! NSSet
      let array = relationship.sortedArray(using: [sort]) as! [NSManagedObject]


      for item in array.enumerated() {
        results.append(item.element)
        print(results)
      }
    }
```

**My data model:**

[image]

I am using a tableView to display my data which works great, now I have implemented a filter function which allows the user to search based on a Clients first name, last name, id etc using NSCompoundPredicate.

I then sort the resulting **[NSManagedObject]** by date using NSSortDescriptor, my aim is to set my **clientResults** variable to contain the SORTED contents of the NSSet. My print statement only outputs that there is one Assessment inside the results variable when in actual fact the NSSet contains two of these NSManagedObjects.

```
let sort:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"dateSorted", ascending: false)

    for (index, ob) in clientResults.enumerated(){

      let relationship = ob.value(forKey: "assessed_by") as! NSSet
      let array = relationship.sortedArray(using: [sort]) as! [NSManagedObject]

      // MARK - I enumerate the contents of the sorted array.

      for item in array.enumerated() {
        results.append(item.element)
        print(results)
      }
    }
```

What is the best practice for assigning the contents of the NSSet to a variable of type [NSManagedObject]?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that elements in `NSSet` are of type `NSManagedObject` why not just do

```
let managedObjectsArray = set.allObjects
```

or if you want to make sure it is of correct type you can do:

```
if let managedObjectsArray = set.allObjects as? [NSManagedObject] {
    //do what you want with [NSManagedObject] array
}
```